# How to Get the Non-Volatile USB Serial Number using VC?

Tags: visual-c++, usb, serial-number

How to Get the Non-Volatile USB Serial Number using VC ?

I know how to get it using C#, but if there is a way to

achieve that in VC?

Comment: How are you getting it in C#?  Are you using ManagementObjectSearcher?

Answer (score 0):

Just found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/DriveInfoEx.aspx) on CodeProject. It uses Managed C++, but it could be of some help to you. Also, [this](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/) may be of interest, its in C++.